# Show icon when boolean field in change_list view of admin with Django-jet

Tags: django, django-admin, django-jet

When showing boolean fields, there's no check/uncheck icon as in the default template of Django Admin.
my Admin model

```
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ['username', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'active']
    search_fields = ['username', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'is_active', 'groups']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix, I just had to override a CSS style in style tag, in base.html that I have overridden admin folder, of it:

```
#changelist-form td.field-active img {
    display: inline-block !important; // we can use also display:block
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to guidance from @ketimaBU i got it working too.

Here's the full solution that worked in my case, using `Django==3.0.2` and `r-django-jet==2.0.8`.

In the project `/templates/admin/` folder add a "base.html" file with following content, to override Jet style:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}

<!-- Show the images for BooleanField -->
{% block extrastyle %}
    <style>
        #changelist-form img {
            display: block; 
        }
    </style>
{% endblock %}
```